# Laravel 5.1 - Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: laravel, mcrypt

I'm a little confused, the [laravel 5.1 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) no longer list Mcrypt as a requirement, and I'm reading in the [release notes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/releases#laravel-5.1) that Mcrypt will no longer be used.

However, when I install laravel using composer, I'm still seeing that 'Mcrypt PHP extension required' message. Am I missing something? Does this need to be disabled in the config or something?

Comment: Are you sure you're installing 5.1 and not 5.0 by accident?

Comment: Yep @ojrask, stupid mistake. Finally checked my version and I had actually managed to install 4.2 :|

Answer (score 0):

Oops... turns out I had installed an older version. Updated to 5.1 and all's well.